# Evalution ∀x.p(x) ⇒ ∃y.q(y,y)

Tags: logic

This is an assignment of introduction to logic on coursera.

Consider a language object constants a and b and relation constants p and q where p has arity 1 and q has arity 2. The following is a truth assignment for this language.

p(a) = 1

p(b) = 0

q(a,a) = 0

q(a,b) = 1

q(b,a) = 1

q(b,b) = 0

Say whether each of the following sentences is true or false under with this truth assignment.

I can't solve the evaluation of this two sentences:

∀x.p(x) ⇒ ∃y.q(y,y)

Here is how I figure,

For ∀x.p(x) ⇒ ∃y.q(y,y). To close the sentence, I got ∀x.∃y.(p(x) ⇒ q(y,y)).Instances of this sentence is a) ∃y.(p(a) ⇒ q(y,y)), b) ∃y.(p(b) ⇒ q(y,y)).If both instances is true according to the truth assignment, then ∀x.p(x) ⇒ ∃y.q(y,y) is true.

First to determine the truth of ∃y.(p(a) ⇒ q(y,y)), find all instances of p(a) ⇒ q(y,y),there are two possibilities,1) p(a) ⇒ q(a,a),2) p(a) ⇒ q(b,b),looking at the truth assignment,p(a) ⇒ q(a,a) is false,p(a) ⇒ q(b,b) is false.Since both these instances is false, the existential sentence ∃y.(p(a) ⇒ q(y,y)) as a whole is false.

Since ∃y.(p(a) ⇒ q(y,y)) is false according to the truth assignment, ∀x.∃y.(p(x) ⇒ q(y,y)) is false, finally ∀x.p(x) ⇒ ∃y.q(y,y) is false, but the answer is TRUE.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: **First of all** you need to figure out whether the formula you're asked to evaluate means $(\forall x.p(x))\to \exists y.q(y,y)$ or $\forall x.(p(x)\to \exists y.q(y,y))$. Unfortunately different authors use different conventions for this, and the two possibilities are not equivalent.

Comment: It's the (∀x.p(x))→∃y.q(y,y), thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\forall x.p(x)$ is false because $p(b)$ is false.  An implication with false antecedent is true, so the sentence is true.

Comment: Note that this assumes that the $\forall x$ ranges only over $p(x)$ and not over the entire implication.

Comment: @HenningMakholm:  good point.  That seems intended to me, but I don't know the definition OP is using for the scope of the quantifiers.

Comment: I should use a parenthesis to make the scope clear, It's (∀x.p(x))→∃y.q(y,y), thanks.